# Send/Receive complex object on SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I'm trying to pass a complex object from server to the client. My **client** code looks like this:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://somewebsite.com/");
var serverHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("searchHub");

serverHub.On<Complex>("newSearch",
    obj =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    });
```

and the `Complex` class is:

```
public class Complex
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int results { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

On the server, I use:

```
public class SearchHub: Hub
{
    public static void NewSearch(string url, string title, int results)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StatsHub>();

        title = Encoder.HtmlEncode(title);
        url = Encoder.UrlEncode(url);
        var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        context.Clients.All.newSearch(url, title, results, date);
    }
}
```

But it's not working. If I remove the type from the `On<Complex>("newSearch"` and use it like `.On("newSearch"`, I get the connection but it only prints the first parameter (the `url`). How should I pass a complex object from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `newSearch` on the server with the primitive types as argument, not a instance of your class. Either change the signature on your client or on the server. They need to match

Comment: Thanks. How can I change it on the **client**?

Comment: "serverHub.On<string, string...>((url ,title..) => {})"

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem. I tried this without adding types to the template but it didn't work. Didn't think of this one.

Comment: You can send reference types too,  but you need to instance a reference on the server and send that instead of the primitive types you have used

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help someone, this is a basic implementation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of images, you should copy the code directly into the post.